# How do I cache dependencies without having knowledge of its version or when it changed?

Tags: caching, github-actions

I have written some code that uses a shell script to download and install a toolchain (that is not mine, but is released on GitHub itself in a `.tar.gz` form). What I wanted to do was that all the artifacts in the latest release of that toolchain be downloaded and saved to a directory which is cached through GitHub actions. And when there is any release newer than the one the cache already has, i.e. `tag` of latest release is not equal to current downloaded release, download newer one and update the existing cache. But reading more of the docs, I found that caches can not be changed. Here is what I currently have in the script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

LATEST_API_URL="https://api.github.com/repos/.../.../releases/latest"

LATEST_TOOLCHAINS_TAG=$(curl -s "$LATEST_API_URL" | grep "tag_name.*" | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d\" -f2)

TOOLCHAINS_PACKED_SAVE_DIR="../toolchains_packed"
ROOT_DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"

cd "$TOOLCHAINS_PACKED_SAVE_DIR"

if [ ! -f "./toolchains_tag.metadata" ]; then
    echo 'NEW FILE' > "./toolchains_tag.metadata"
fi

if [ "$LATEST_TOOLCHAINS_TAG" != "$(cat "./toolchains_tag.metadata")" ]; then
    DOWNLOADS_URLS=$(curl -s "$LATEST_API_URL" | grep "browser_download_url.*tar.gz" | cut -d: -f2,3 | tr -d \")

    wget $DOWNLOADS_URLS || { printf "wget failed: Please read above errors.\nExiting!\n"; exit 1; }

    echo "$LATEST_TOOLCHAINS_TAG" > "./toolchains_tag.metadata"
fi

for tar_pkg in *.tar.gz; do
    [ ! -f "$tar_pkg" ] && { printf "No *.tar.gz found.\nExiting\n"; exit 1; }

    CURR_COMP=$(echo "$tar_pkg" | cut -d. -f1)
    COMPILERS_LIST="$COMPILERS_LIST$CURR_COMP\n"

    sudo tar -xzvf "$tar_pkg" -C /
done

printf "$COMPILERS_LIST" > "./compilers_list.metadata"

cd $ROOT_DIR
```

And in the workflow file:

```yml
...
jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Create toolchains Directory
      run: mkdir ../toolchains_packed
    - name: Get Cached toolchains Directory
      uses: actions/cache@v3.2.3
      with:
        path: ../toolchains_packed
        key: toolchains_packed
    - name: Setup toolchains
      run: ./path/to/the_script.sh
...
```

*NOTE: This code works successfully in fetching the latest release, and as intended also doesn't fetch one when there is no update available. I only ask for a way using which I can replace older cache with newer one.*

How I previously understood caching on GitHub was that caches automatically updated over different runs of a workflow. But now, what I read is not only that caches do not update automatically, they can never update. As a result, the current scenario is that once the GitHub cache is generated, it will never be updated again, and the script will have to download the packages every time, making the entire point of caching null. So, I usually also have to keep an eye on latest release of the toolchain and delete the cache manually if update available.

---

**Personal Thoughts on the Issue:** I have thoughts whether I can name my caches using the tag present at `../toolchains/toolchains_tag.metadata`. But that too is present in the cache, and hence I don't know how can I do this.

---

**Final Question:** How can I update my code such that I do not have to do any manual stuff for updating the cache every time there is a new release available for the toolchain?

Comment: Is a new release supposed to build your code too? If yes, depending on the frequency of the releases, you can schedule a cron job to check and download the new release. If there's a new release, your normal build workflow would run. Caching would be part of your normal workflow so no change would be required there. And, if it's your normal workflow, the cache is already there so no need to fetch it when it's already there. There may be an extra step for the version though. In that separate step, the version would be checked, verified, and set if required e.g. to an env var `TOOLCHAIN_VERSION`.

Comment: The fetched `TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` could be used in the cache and for the rest of the workflow, maybe to set the `GITHUB_PATH` so that the executables are available wherever needed.

Comment: The above comments as per my understanding of your use case. If I missed or misunderstood something, please highlight that. I'll think about that and comment here if I have something more to add. Thanks!

Comment: Also, as part of that cron job, you can evict the older cache entries using this action (https://github.com/actions/gh-actions-cache).

Comment: @Azeem, thank you for your comments. I will take a deeper look at them later on (its past my sleep time now). Just looking at them once, I just wanted to say that my builds are supposed to be run manually by me. And I think the tag itself acts as version. Also, `$PATH` is set in other script which handles compilation, so no need to set that in this script. I think I can make use of the action you posted, maybe adding it to cron scheduled separate workflow, or otherwise doing the stuff in this workflow itself - as I said, I'll take a look at them tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. I tried viewing some real life examples from different repos on GitHub and taking inspiration from @Azeem's comments, made some changes which worked well. Here is the edited script:-

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# The code is split into three parts:-
#   1. Code to check for available update ('-c' cmd line option)
#   2. Code to download available update ('-d' cmd line option) -- ran only
#      when '-c' returned with code '1'.
#   3. Code to install toolchains ('-i' cmd line option)

LATEST_API_URL="https://api.github.com/repos/.../releases/latest"

TOOLCHAINS_PACKED_SAVE_DIR="../toolchains_packed"
ROOT_DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"

LATEST_TOOLCHAINS_TAG="$(curl -s "$LATEST_API_URL" | grep "tag_name" | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d\" -f2)"

cd "$TOOLCHAINS_PACKED_SAVE_DIR"

case $1 in
-c)
    UPDATE_AVAILABLE=0

    if [ ! -f ./toolchains_tag.metadata ]; then
        echo 'NEW FILE' > ./toolchains_tag.metadata
        UPDATE_AVAILABLE=1
    fi

    if [ "$LATEST_TOOLCHAINS_TAG" != "$(cat ./toolchains_tag.metadata)" ]; then
        rm -rf ./*
        UPDATE_AVAILABLE=1
    fi

    exit $UPDATE_AVAILABLE
    ;;
-d)
    TC_DOWNLOADS_URLS="$(curl -s "$LATEST_API_URL" | grep "browser_download_url" | cut -d: -f2,3 | tr -d \")"

    echo "wget -t 3 $TC_DOWNLOADS_URLS"

    wget -t 3 $TC_DOWNLOADS_URLS || { printf "wget failed: Please read above errors.\nExiting!\n"; exit 1; }

    echo "$LATEST_TOOLCHAINS_TAG" > ./toolchains_tag.metadata
    ;;
-i)
    for tar_pkg in *.tar.gz; do
        [ ! -f "$tar_pkg" ] && { printf "No *.tar.gz found.\nExiting\n"; exit 1; }

        CURR_COMP=$(echo "$tar_pkg" | cut -d. -f1)
        COMPILERS_LIST="$COMPILERS_LIST$CURR_COMP\n"

        sudo tar -xzf "$tar_pkg" -C /
    done

    printf "$COMPILERS_LIST" > "./compilers_list.metadata"
    ;;
esac

cd $ROOT_DIR
exit 0
```

and the edited workflow file:-

```yml
...
jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Create toolchains Directory
      run: |
        mkdir -p toolchains_packed
        ln -s `pwd`/toolchains_packed ../toolchains_packed
    - name: Get Cached toolchains Directory
      uses: actions/cache@v3.2.3
      with:
        path: toolchains_packed
        key: toolchains_packed-${{ github.sha }}
        restore-keys: toolchains_packed-
    - name: Check For toolchains' Update
      id: toolchains_update_check
      run: |
        if ! ./build_helper/github/setup_toolchains.sh -c; then
          echo "update_available=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        else
          echo "update_available=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        fi
    - name: Delete toolchains' Cache
      if: steps.toolchains_update_check.outputs.update_available == 'true'
      uses: snnaplab/delete-branch-cache-action@v1.0.0
    - name: Download toolchains' Update
      if: steps.toolchains_update_check.outputs.update_available == 'true'
      run: ./build_helper/github/setup_toolchains.sh -d
    - name: Install toolchains
      run: ./build_helper/github/setup_toolchains.sh -i
...
```

---

**Explanation:**

I changed my script to make it capable of performing three distinct tasks:-

1. Check if the cache was latest (or if there was even any cache)
2. Download update (the workflow runs it only if (1) returns something which would tell it that update is available -- exit code `1` in this case)
3. Install toolchain (ran everytime -- caching is done for packed `.tar.gz`s only).

Also, I changed my workflow to make it do these things (in order):-

1. **Get cache** [NOTE: As `...-${{ github.sha }}` is used as primary key of the cache, the code will fail to update cache if workflow is run without any new commit.]
2. **Check for available update availability** [by making use of the script]

*`(3)` and `(4)` are run only if `(2)` succeeded, i.e. the script returned with exit code `1`.*

3. **Delete cache** [NOTE: For sake of simplicity, I used `snnaplab/delete-branch-cache-action@v1.0.0` which deletes all existing caches in the branch. If you want to preserve any cache, please use [gh-actions-cache](https://github.com/actions/gh-actions-cache).]
4. **Download update**
5. **Install update**